# facebook app crash after sending graph story with user generated image

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, bitmap

I'm using this code to submit a custom action to facebook using a custom bitmap:

```
//object
            OpenGraphObject pic = OpenGraphObject.Factory.createForPost("mobileglobalshapers:globalpicture");
            pic.setProperty("title","Shape Latam");
            //pic.setProperty("image","https://emaginelab.com/globalshapers/public/placeholder_400.jpg");
            pic.setProperty("description","test description");
            pic.setProperty("url","http://emaginelab.com/globalshapers/public/object.html");

            List<Bitmap> images = new ArrayList<Bitmap>();
            images.add(combineInnerViews(imagesWrapper));

            //action
            OpenGraphAction action = GraphObject.Factory.create(OpenGraphAction.class);
            action.setType("mobileglobalshapers:take");
            action.setProperty("globalpicture",pic);

            //show
            FacebookDialog shareDialog = new FacebookDialog.OpenGraphActionDialogBuilder(this,action,"globalpicture")
                    .setImageAttachmentsForObject("globalpicture",images,true)
                    .build();
            uiHelper.trackPendingDialogCall(shareDialog.present());
```

Here combineInnerViews(imagesWrapper) return a bitmap.

The problem is that when i call this method, facebook app crashes without showing, and it automatically returns me to the app. It doesn't produce any logs, so i don't know what can be wrong.

Note: this error doesn't seems to happen in devices with OS older than 4.1. I have tested it in a Galaxy S2 and a Galaxy Ace (4.1.2 and 2.3.6) and it won't crash.

I'm using facebook SDK 3.8.0

Any reason why this is happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Never mind, I found the reason.

When declaring the content provider in the AndroidManifest.xml, you need to add this property:

```
 android:exported="true"
```

otherwise the OS will throw a security exception and the facebook intent will crash